# Function indicates tensor as a scalar

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make a function with 64x1 size input, and returns a 64x1 size output.(each element is computed by y=a*x+bx^2+cx^3+(1-a-b-c)x^4)

So, I wrote this function.

```
# Polynomial with 4th degree
batch_size = 64

def polyMm4(a_v, x):
  mtx_xpower = np.random.rand(batch_size,4)
  mtx_xpower[:,0:1] = x
  mtx_xpower[:,1:2] = np.power(x,2)
  mtx_xpower[:,2:3] = np.power(x,3)
  mtx_xpower[:,3:4] = np.power(x,4)

  mtx_coeff = np.random.rand(1, 4)
  print('\na_v: ')
  mtx_coeff[0][0] = a_v[0]
  mtx_coeff[0][1] = a_v[1]
  mtx_coeff[0][2] = a_v[2]
  mtx_coeff[0][3] = 1-a_v[0]-a_v[1]-a_v[2]

  y = np.matmul(mtx_xpower, mtx_coeff)

  output = np.random.rand(1,1)
  output[0][0] = y
  output = torch.from_numpy(output).float()

  return output
```

And run this code to check function runs properly.

```
coe = np.random.rand(1,3)
coe[0][0] = float(1)
coe[0][1] = float(0)
coe[0][2] = float(0)
print('Coeff: ')
print(coe)

x = np.random.rand(64,1)
print('\n10 inputs: ')
print(x[0:10])

y = polyMm4_v(coe, x)
```

But it says: *----> mtx_coeff[0][0] = a_v[0]*

*IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.*

I think this is odd, since a_v must be form of 1x3 tensor(not a scalar).

Can anyone help me why this code runs like this?

Comment: 'must be' - is that your hope, or is it a verifiable fact?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [115]: batch_size = 64
     ...: 
     ...: def polyMm4(a_v, x):
     ...:   mtx_xpower = np.random.rand(batch_size,4)
     ...:   mtx_xpower[:,0:1] = x
     ...:   mtx_xpower[:,1:2] = np.power(x,2)
     ...:   mtx_xpower[:,2:3] = np.power(x,3)
     ...:   mtx_xpower[:,3:4] = np.power(x,4)
     ...: 
     ...:   mtx_coeff = np.random.rand(1, 4)
     ...:   print('\na_v: ')
     ...:   mtx_coeff[0][0] = a_v[0]
     ...:   mtx_coeff[0][1] = a_v[1]
     ...:   mtx_coeff[0][2] = a_v[2]
     ...:   mtx_coeff[0][3] = 1-a_v[0]-a_v[1]-a_v[2]
     ...: 
     ...:   y = np.matmul(mtx_xpower, mtx_coeff)
     ...: 
     ...:   output = np.random.rand(1,1)
     ...:   output[0][0] = y
     ...:   #output = torch.from_numpy(output).float()
     ...:   return output
     ...: 
In [116]: coe = np.random.rand(1,3)
     ...: coe[0][0] = float(1)
     ...: coe[0][1] = float(0)
     ...: coe[0][2] = float(0)
     ...: print('Coeff: ')
     ...: print(coe)
     ...: 
     ...: x = np.random.rand(64,1)
     ...: print('\n10 inputs: ')
     ...: print(x[0:10])
     ...: 
Coeff: 
[[1. 0. 0.]]

10 inputs: 
[[0.42341116]
 [0.19069873]
 [0.84683281]
 [0.18538824]
 [0.60934426]
 [0.2040253 ]
 [0.25835956]
 [0.73836755]
 [0.24823984]
 [0.93009243]]
```

first error:

```
In [117]: y = polyMm4_v(coe, x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [117] in <cell line: 1>
    y = polyMm4_v(coe, x)
NameError: name 'polyMm4_v' is not defined
```

then your error:

```
In [118]: y = polyMm4(coe, x)

a_v: 
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [118] in <cell line: 1>
    y = polyMm4(coe, x)
  Input In [115] in polyMm4
    mtx_coeff[0][0] = a_v[0]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`coe` is a (1,3), `coe[0]` is a (3,):

```
In [119]: coe
Out[119]: array([[1., 0., 0.]])
In [120]: coe[0]
Out[120]: array([1., 0., 0.])
```

`mtx_coeff` is a (1,4); double indexed it's a single element slot:

```
In [121]: mtx_coeff = np.random.rand(1, 4)
In [122]: mtx_coeff[0][0]
Out[122]: 0.2869346888553528
```

Hence the `setting array element with sequence`

Setting it to one value

```
In [124]: mtx_coeff[0][0] = coe[0][0]
```

works, but trying to set it to 3 does not.

In retrospect, I should have voted to close this question because it did not provide the FULL error message.

And in contrast to your subject line, this has nothing to do with `tensorflow`.